# Not able to access protected member variable of Parent Kotlin class in Java child class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
abstract class Parent {

    protected var name : String

}

class Child extends Parent {

    private void childMethod() {
         name = "child";
    }
}
```

in Child class it gives me error **name has private access in x.x.x.Child** (x.x.x is package name)

Answer (score 2):

In java child class we can access the protected member variable of parent as getName().
Like a getter method is auto-generated.
I am new to Kotlin, need to dig out more how the method is auto-generated.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties

Comment: Here you need the setter `setName("child")`, not the getter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access it as a field from Java, you should annotate the Kotlin property with [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields).  Note that per that link, you can only annotate a property with `@JvmField` if it has a backing field, is not private, does not have `open`, `override` or `const` modifiers, and is not a delegated property (none of which apply here, so you're fine).